# start Collabora with docker on Odroid U3 with Ubuntu 14.04 throws error: System error: exec format error

Tags: ubuntu, docker, odroid

On Odroid U3 with Ubuntu 14.04 running I try to get Collabora to work with Docker for Nextcloud.

```
Linux Kernel Version 3.8.13

Docker Version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2
```

I pulled Collabora using: `docker pull collabora/code`

When I try to start Docker with Collabora with `sudo docker run -t -d -p 127.0.0.1:9980:9980 --restart always --cap-add MKNOD collabora/code` it throws the following error:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619: [8] System error: exec format error
```

I googled a lot but cannot find any solution. The docker logfile says this:

```
INFO[3525] POST /v1.18/containers/create                
INFO[3525] +job create()                                
INFO[3525] +job log(create, 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619, collabora/code:latest) 
INFO[3525] -job log(create, 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619, collabora/code:latest) = OK (0) 
INFO[3525] -job create() = OK (0)                       
INFO[3525] POST /v1.18/containers/9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619/start 
INFO[3525] +job start(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) 
INFO[3525] No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4] 
INFO[3525] +job allocate_interface(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) 
INFO[3525] -job allocate_interface(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) = OK (0) 
INFO[3525] +job allocate_port(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) 
INFO[3525] -job allocate_port(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) = OK (0) 
INFO[3525] +job log(start, 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619, collabora/code:latest) 
INFO[3525] -job log(start, 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619, collabora/code:latest) = OK (0) 
WARN[3525] exit status 1                                
INFO[3525] +job release_interface(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) 
INFO[3525] -job release_interface(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) = OK (0) 
INFO[3525] +job release_interface(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) 
INFO[3525] Unable to unmap port 127.0.0.1:9980: port is not mapped 
INFO[3525] -job release_interface(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) = OK (0) 
INFO[3525] +job log(die, 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619, collabora/code:latest) 
INFO[3525] -job log(die, 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619, collabora/code:latest) = OK (0) 
Cannot start container 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619: [8] System error: exec format error
INFO[3525] -job start(9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619) = ERR (1) 
ERRO[3525] Handler for POST /containers/{name:.*}/start returned error: Cannot start container 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619: [8] System error: exec format error 
ERRO[3525] HTTP Error: statusCode=500 Cannot start container 9e7590d0f3ff444b721f544bea8b2ba1584c8c527d4a88bfd27e1b1f7bdd0619: [8] System error: exec format error
```

Any Ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Exec format error indicates that the compiled code is not cross platform. So whichever executable this runs is not ok with your Host OS

Comment: You are right. I just found out that Collabora is not available for arm - at least not precompiled. Thanks for your help. I didn't think about that in the first place because I installed docker.io from normal repositories and assumed that it will only pull images which are compiled for the same architecture. This is obviously not the case.